# Index Placement for Spinors in Relativity

Tags: relativity, notation, conventions, representation-theory, spinors

This may ultimately be a silly question, but a pedantic mind like mine gets tied into knots over differing notation. (Disclaimer: I'm a mathematician.)

Let $\mathbb{W}$ be a complex two-dimensional vector space which carries the fundamental representation of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ by letting $M\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ act by matrix multiplication. The elements of $\mathbb{W}$ are called $\textit{left-handed Weyl spinors}$, if I understand the physics terminology correctly.

My issue is the following: After picking a basis of $\mathbb{W}$, we can write elements in component notation. Some authors have the convention that $\mathbb{W}\ni w=w^{\alpha} s_{\alpha}$ where the $w^{\alpha}$ are the numerical components. (For an example, see Appendix A in this link: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jmf/Teaching/Lectures/BUSSTEPP.pdf) Consequently, $M\cdot w=M^{\alpha}\,_{\beta} w^{\beta}$. This makes good sense to me on the grounds that spinors should be analogous to vectors and thus have upper indices. But certain deviant authors (see section 5.4 of http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~jbg34/Site/Resources/lectnotes%28master%29.pdf, for example) insist on $w=w_{\alpha} s^{\alpha}$ so $M\cdot w=M_{\alpha}\,^{\beta} w_{\beta}$. So there seems to be a conflict between upper and lower index spinors.

Is there any good reason for this disagreement in notation? Is one convention superior to the other? Is this issue totally inconsequential? I'll be grateful for any perspective.

Comment: Note that cross posting is typically frowned upon. It probably would be best to wait & see how this question goes; if you don't get anything you can either re-ask it on [math.se] or request migration (which is the preferred method).

Comment: I thought cross posting might be a problem; at least now I know. I deleted my post on math stack.

Comment: One may lower an upstairs spinor index with the SL(2,C) invariant Levi-Civita tensor $\epsilon_{AB}$. Therefore spinors with upstairs and downstairs indices carry equivalent irreps of SL(2,C) and so they represent the same physical quantity. It therefore doesn't matter whether your theory uses $\psi^{A}$ or $\psi_{A}$.

Comment: I don't think your comment addresses my question. I'm wondering whether there are good reasons for the difference in notation, as I don't think notation is arbitrary and whimsical. My assumption is that there must be good reasons to prefer one convention to the other, and I am looking to discern what they may be.